# Archive option won't enable

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I need to create an IPA file of iOS app, already created the distribution profile, and certificate. But on build settings under Code Signing options I am unable to see valid certificate, it is mentioned `(no profiles currently match)`, also on `Product > Archive`, Archive option is disable.

What am i missing?

Comment: had exactly same simptomps a week or two ago: it turned out that last letter of application bundle was missing when i was creating app id in iTunes. First thing to do is to check everything letter by letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you made sure that IOS device is selected in the top left hand drop down and **not** iPhone Simulator. It won't be enabled unless iOS device is selected.